# Should I iterate over a directed graph using Iterative deepening depth-first search (IDDFS)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Example: I have 20 persons as object, and every person knows 0-n others. The direction of the link matters! A person A might know B, but B might not know A. It's a directed graph.

**Edit:** *For simplification, my node objects (in this case Person objects) are able to store arbitrary information. I know this is not the best design but for now that would be fine.*

So in the worst case everyone is connected with everyone else, everyone knows everyone else.
This is no real use case but I want to write a test for this to learn and play around. In a productive environment the number of objects would be limited to about 20, but the ways in which those objects are connected to eachother are unlimited.

This illustrates the problem in a simplified way:
[image: graph] [thanks to source](http://labspace.open.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=5022)

Given a specific person as starting point, I want to walk through the whole graph and examine every possible path exactly once without getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Let's imagine person A knows B, who knows C, and who knows A. The output might be:

A knows B knows C knows A (ok but we don't want to end in an infinite loop so we stop here)
A knows C knows A
A knows T knows R knows V

This would be stupid and must be eliminated:
A knows B knows C knows A knows C knows A knows T knows R knows V ...

I do have a couple of crazy ideas how to tackle this problem. But...

Question) Must I do that with an Iterative deepening depth-first search (IDDFS)?

---

Jon was so kind to point out [DFS on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

I'm stuck with this part in the article:
[image: wikipedia]

> a depth-first search starting at A,
>   assuming that the left edges in the
>   shown graph are chosen before right
>   edges, and assuming the search
>   remembers previously-visited nodes and
>   will not repeat them (since this is a
>   small graph), will visit the nodes in
>   the following order: A, B, D, F, E, C,
>   G. The edges traversed in this search
>   form a Trémaux tree, a structure with
>   important applications in graph
>   theory.

specifically this note:

> "(since this is a small graph)"

OK so what if this is a huge graph?

Comment: If its a huge graph, it will take a long time, as it will explore leftmost to rightmost in the tree.

Comment: In a real use case it will be a small graph of maybe 20 nodes in the worst case. But I just don't want any limitation regarding allowed connections.

Comment: "Make it work, then make it fast."

Comment: Yeah I really don't care about speed right now. I'll throw a donut party when it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is indeed a graph.

I hate to provide such a bare answer, but the question is so basic that [Graph Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) on Wikipedia is more than adequate. The two basic approaches are explained and there is also pseudocode.

Comment: That's what Wikipedia says about it: "Tree traversal is a special case of graph traversal. In contrast to tree traversal, in general graph traversal, each node may have to be visited more than once, and a root-like node that connects to all other nodes might not exist." <<< So the article does not even tackle the problem of graph traversal where a node might have to be visited multiple times.

Comment: @BugAlert: What does tree traversal have to do with this? I hope you didn't click on *that* link. The *graph traversal* strategies most definitely tackle the problem of traversing a... graph.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to direct me to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)? I know that page but as I said, it tells me next to nothing. Hoped for some help on SO.

Comment: There are about 4 links on that page (not taking into account the interface chrome around). First one is about graph theory in general. Second one about tree traversal. Third abour DFS, fourth about BFS. Why don't you just give the right link when you see it there :-))

Comment: @BugAlert: This page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search (which is linked to in the Graph Traversal link) says it all, *including* pseudocode. I think you should read up on a little terminology first (graph, node, vertex, edge) and you 'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I should mention the authors title and question has changed so much, some of the information in this answer may not be 100% relevant.

As Jon has already mentioned, this is indeed, a graph. A directed graph in fact.

I suggest you look at [Adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), they will provide you with direct insight as to how you can reach a solution.
I imagine your original *lazy* solution was probably something akin to an [Adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list); which is fine, but isn't as easy to implement, and also may be harder to traverse. There is two main differences between the two.

Adjacency lists will take up more space, but may be nicer in larger networks in minimizing computation over unconnected nodes; whereas adjacency matrices are are little more friendly, but store data for every edge, regardless of whether it exists (connected) or not.

The primary concern I found when using adjacency lists, was not their theoretical space, but in C++, I was storing each connected node as a pointer in a vector inside each node; this could get way out of hand as soon as the network got bigger, and was very unfriendly to visualize as well as managing new nodes and deleting nodes.
In comparison with adjacency matrices, which have a single reference for all nodes (can be stored in a single vector of nodes) and can be easily modified.

---

If your question is truly about traversal, then if your graph is implemented as an adjacency matrix, as a vector of vectors, traversal is simple. See below pseudocode:

To read (for each neuron) all neurons a neuron's axon is connected to (ie neuron outputs)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // adjacency matrix is n * n
    Neuron& neuron = nodes[i];
    for (size_t j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Axon_connection& connection = edges[j][i];
        if (connection.exists()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To read all (for each neuron) neurons a neuron's dendrites are connected to (ie neuron inputs)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // adjacency matrix is n * n
    Neuron& neuron = nodes[i];
    for (size_t j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Dendrite& dendrite = edges[j][i];
        if (dendrite.exists()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note this second method may not be cache friendly for big networks, depending on your implementation.
The exists method simply ensures the adjacency matrix bit is set to true, you can then implement other data such as strengths in these edges.

Comment: I should note that I want to use that on a smartphone :-) so memory is critical.

Comment: I updated my answer, this should be very memory friendly, as long as you use adjacency matrices. In my own implementation, I use (n*24)+24 bytes just for the vectors, and then n^2 bytes for the adjacency matrix. Assuming you store connection costs in a float in each edge, that will be n^2 * sizeof(float). On a smart phone, assuming you use minimal memory for data structures, you could guess at: (20^2 * 4) + (20^2 * 1) = (400 * 4) + 400 = 2000 bytes < 2KB.

Comment: Looks good, but I'm not using adjacency matrices. That's way above my brain capacity right now. Every Person object has an array that links all other known Person objects (and so forth).

Comment: That is essentially an adjacency list, and is no doubt making traversal a task and a half. Maybe show us what you have, and we can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Objective-C. The code is spread across my other questions asked previously. Can you explain the part with the governing array of all nodes? Is that for keeping track of visited state?

Comment: No, I am not referring to DFS or BFS in my answer. I did not mean to confuse you with that statement about an array of nodes, and have hence removed it from my comment.

Answer (score 2):

My friend, you have posted many very [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472300/bugalert#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_recent-ansort_recent) over the last day or two. I suggest you take a little bit of time out and read an introductory textbook on graph theory, or find some [lectures](http://academicearth.org/) on the subject.

Then you will at least know how to recognize and classify the standard problems. All you are going to get on SO are links back to such resources - it's not worth anyone's time writing out a fresh exposition. When you have a specific question, or are stuck understanding a particular issue, then ask and we will be happy to help, but you need to meet us half-way.

To answer your question, you can perform depth first search and breadth first search on an arbitrary graph as you have previously done on a tree - you just need to keep track of which nodes you have visited. Look out for this in any code/pseudocode you encounter. You don't have to keep track of visited notes on a tree (as in your other questions), as a tree is a special instance of a graph (a connected acyclic graph) which cannot be "wildly interconnected".

Comment: I will be updating my question as I walk through this. So when I remember which node was visited, how would I tackle nodes that can be visited many times because of multiple incoming and outgoing connections from loopbacks?

Comment: When you first visit a node, mark it as visited. You then only visit children/neighbours that are not yet visited.

Comment: Imagine you have a group of friends, and each friend has some of the other friends in their address book. If you want to spread some news around the group, you would start by phoning everyone in your address book and say "here' some news, tell all your friends". When each person then phones their friends, the recipient would say "I've already heard the news and passed it on, thanks." and wouldn't pass on the message a second time.

Comment: That's a good explanation. I wonder why those articles can't write it that way.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your original question, it is definitely theoretically possible to solve. However if you are after the shortest path then this looks suspiciously like the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) which is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

In any case, there are many different graph traversal algorithms (DFS, IDDFS, BFS, etc) which could be of use.

Comment: The shortest path is easy to find with a simple breadth-first search.  However you're right that the stated problem will result in a huge search space.

Comment: I've implemented DFS and tested it with this kind of graph. It gets stuck with loops. So as no looping connections are produced that's fine. But otherwise it crashes.

Comment: If you mark nodes as visited then you can make sure you only visit nodes you haven't seen before.

Comment: Sure, but I must walk though all possible paths. A node can be visited multiple times. I'm thinking of railroads and railroad-switches. Will have to build a physical model to play around with.

Answer (score 1):

One way (and not, necessarily, the best way) to do this is to modify the graph.

For example, say that the graph initially encodes A-->B-->C.  If the edge A-->C does not exist, add the edge A-->C.

You can do this for each node in your graph to explicitly state which nodes know each other.

Comment: Why should I add the edge A-->C if it is already there? Also, those Person objects already have an array pointing to every other person they know.

Comment: Sorry about that, typo:)  My understanding was, for the path A-->B-->C, A does not immediately know C, but must infer that it knows C.  The approach I gave simply says, "once you infer that you know someone, make that knowledge explicit in the graph."